# Can't get complete json data through webservice

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get large amount of data in form of json through https://www.cyb3rpirat3s.in/android/leaderboard.php website..but the problem is that after getting some amount of data from above link the logcat throughs error that it cannot parse json(due to incomplete getting of json).I am new to android and don't know how should i handle large amount of json.. I have even seacrhed for it but was not able to find relevant information.
Thanks in advance

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                int status=httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if(status==200){
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    String data=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    json=data.split("<!--")[0];
                    Log.d("sdjb",json);
                }           
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
           Log.d("sf",jObj.getString("success"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
            return jObj;
    }
```

logcat errror:

> 11-13 19:03:22.873: E/JSON Parser(7979): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"rank":1,"1":"11","level":"11","0":"the_godfather","piratename":"the_godfather"},{"rank":2,"1":"6","level":"6","0":"ShiniGami","piratename":"ShiniGami"},{"rank":3,"1":"6","level":"6","0":"hurricane","piratename":"hurricane"},{"rank":4,"1":"6","level":"6","0":"the_batman","piratename":"the_batman"},{"rank":5,"1":"6","level":"6","0":"the_boatswain","piratename":"the_boatswain"},{"rank":6,"1":"5","level":"5","0":"battlemonger","piratename":"battlemonger"},{"rank":7,"1":"5","level":"5","0":"MishuAnubis","piratename":"MishuAnubis"},{"rank":8,"1":"5","level":"5","0":"YogeshPatil","piratename":"YogeshPatil"},{"rank":

Comment: sorry my mistake....

Answer (score 0):

try with this method might help you.

```
public static JSONObject JsonHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";
    try {


        if (method == "GET") {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

Comment: this method won't work ... because get method would limit the size of json

Comment: but you can remove that if condition simply..but why downvote??

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the wrong key

`Log.d("sf",jObj.getString("success"));`

there is no key named `"success"`

Do this way:

```
jObj.getString("piratename");
jObj.getString("level");
jObj.getString("rank");
jObj.getString("0");
jObj.getString("1");
```

Comment: exception is thrown before it gets to Log.d("sf",jObj.getString("success"))..the case u told would have given me nullpointerexception ...i didnt downvote u